# How to Host Jupyter Notebook as a website from a terminal only Linux

Tags: python, web, jupyter-notebook

Given a Terminal Only Mode of Ubuntu, is it possible to host Jupiter notebook and the GUI can be accessed over Http(/s) from another device ?

If not, then, the Jupyter notebook running on the GUI platform of a Linux box , How can the access be made public so that the Jupyter NoteBook on a Linux Box can be used as a Private Cloud service ?

Comment: Yes, see https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html

Comment: Yes, see https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html